Fixed packet size in low-latency rtp stream using queues
I am trying to stream a v4l2src source encoded as h265, with low latency mode turned on.
Below is the gstreamer command I use.
 gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw, format=NV12, width=1920, height=1080, framerate=60/1 ! omxh265enc target-bitrate=2000 control-rate=low-latency num-slices=15 periodicity-idr=10 skip-frame=false ! h265parse ! queue min-threshold-bytes=200 ! rtph265pay mtu=200 ! udpsink host=192.168.1.16 port=5004 sync=false buffer-size=200 blocksize=200
I am trying to implement a queue as suggested here to stream packets of fixed length. However, I still can see packets of varying size in Wireshark. rtph265pay mtu=200 sets an upperbound to the stream but packets are varied in size. I am willing to sacrifice a bit of latency to achieve constant packet size.
What should be modified in order to get constant packet size in the stream?
I tried changing the queue position in the pipeline. Also tried to using the rtph265pay's property min-ptime to achieve constant packet size.

If you are seeing varying packet sizes after making this change, you may need to experiment with different values for "min-ptime" to find the optimal setting for your requirements.
